# Google "Cloud Tools for Team Foundation Server" not available on VSTS Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

"Cloud Tools for Team Foundation Server" from Google Cloud Platform indicates that it should be available on the Visual Studio Marketplace but I can't find it?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-tfs

Has anyone used this plugin or know if this was/is actually available on the marketplace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-tfs/issues/65) issue on GitHub, the extension not available on the marketplace for now:

> Currently the project is marked as private on the Marketplace as we
>   evaluate the extension.

You still can use the extension in this way:

- Download the extension from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-tfs/releases) (the `vsix` file).
- Go to `http://{tfs-server}:8080/tfs/_gallery/manage`.
- Click on "Upload new extension" and choose the `vsix` file.
- Click on the `...` near the extension name.
- Click "Install".
- A new window will be opened, click "Continue" and "Confirm".

Now the extension installed and you can choose the GCP tasks on the build:

[image]